# CMake Library from subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build a C++ project using CMake. Therefore I'd like to create a library from a subdirectory. My project structure looks like the following:

```
project
  core
    CMakeLists.txt
    point.h
    point.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
  build
  main.cpp
```

My outer CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(MyProject)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(core)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main core)
```

My inner CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(
    core
    point.cpp
)
```

I'm importing point.h in my main.cpp file with `#include "core/point.h"`
When I run cmake from the build folder no error occurs. Building using make gives me the following error:

```
fatal error: point.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "core/point.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce using VS 2019. Which build system/compiler are you using? Have you modified the project adding the include dir and the build system  did not pick up the change automatically? (try running `cmake <build dir>` and then `cmake --build <build dir>` and see if this works). Here are some things I'd improve in your project though: I prefer adding include dirs per target, i.e. use `target_include_directories`.

Comment: Furthermore libs should automatically provide their own include dirs and public includes go into a seperate dir; move `point.h` to `core/include/core/point.h` and add `target_include_directories(core PUBLIC include)` perhaps adding `PRIVATE include/core` to the end, if you need to access `point.h` as `#include "point.h"` in `point.cpp`; this way any target linking `core` automatically is able to use `#include "core/point.h"` to include `point.h` regardless of the relative location without having to use `[target_]include_directories`